# Passing Gitlab CI variables to Google Cloud Secret Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci, cicd, google-secret-manager

I have variables in my `gitlab CI` that I want to pass to `GCP secret manager` through my CI/CD piepeline.

I found this command that allows me to create a single secret :

```
gcloud secrets create secret-id --data-file="/path/to/file.txt"
```

But when it comes to multiple variables it becomes very complicated.

Is there a way to create multiple secrets in the same time through `gcloud command` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

You can add a custom `shell` script to do that.

For example, for your your `GCP` Secret env vars, you can add a naming convention and the same prefix :

```bash
# Your Gitlab env vars
export GCP_SECRET_ENV_NAME=secret_name
export GCP_SECRET_ENV_VALUE=secret_value
```

Then you can add this kind of script and add a foreach on all your secret variables :

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -o pipefail
set -u

# Simulate your Gitlab secrets
export GCP_SECRET_ENV_NAME=secret_name
export GCP_SECRET_ENV_VALUE=secret_value

for var_name in "${!GCP_SECRET@}"; do
  echo "##### var name"
  echo $var_name

  echo "##### var value"
  echo "${!var_name}"

  gcloud secrets create $var_name --data-file="${!var_name}"
done
```

- This script loop on all your secret starting with `GCP_SECRET`
- Then you can access to the key and value of the env var
- You can execute your `gcloud` command on each secret var

**Solution 2 :**

You can also think about `File` type variable in `Gitlab` : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-types

From the documentation :

```
Use File type CI/CD variables for tools that need a file as input.

File type variables:

Consist of a key, value and file.
Are made available in jobs as environment variables, with
The CI/CD variable key as the environment variable name.
The CI/CD variable value saved to a temporary file.
The path to the temporary file as the environment variable value.
```

**Solution 3 :**

- Create directly the secrets without versions (values) in `Secret manager` with an infra as code tool like `Terraform`
- Add the versions (values) manually in `Secret manager`

This solution is less automatic for secret versions but more secure, because we don't set secrets and sensitive values in `Gitlab`, `Terraform` `tfstate` or other places.